# Python scikit-learn: prediction on dataset with text and numeric variables

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of projects for which I want to predict the outcome (success/fail) using Python and scikit-learn. The dataset contains a mixture of data types: project title, project description, etc. are text columns. Project cost on the other hand is a numeric field.

I would like to transform the text columns using TF-IDF which I can use as input for my model. Here's my code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train['Project Title'] = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train['Project Title'])
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)
```

Any ideas why this error is showing?

EDIT: example data below

```
Project Title   Project Essay   Project Short Description   Project Need Statement  Project Cost    Project Type ID Project Subject Category Tree ID    Project Subject Subcategory Tree ID Project Resource Category ID    Project Grade Level Category ID Project Current Status ID
Stand Up to Bullying: Together We Can!  Did you know that 1-7 students in grades K-12 ...   Did you know that 1-7 students in grades K-12 ...   My students need 25 copies of "Bullying in Sch...   361.80  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: can you add the data?

Comment: What is the `shape` of `X` and `y`?

Comment: @feliks shape of X and y: (51908, 11) and (51908,)

Comment: @seralouk I've added example data

Comment: OK. Please add the data or parts of it so we can reproduce the error with your provided code snippet, as @seralouk pointed out.

Comment: @feliks I just did

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you use `TfidfTransformer` which transforms a count matrix to a normalized tf or tf-idf representation instead of `TfidfVectorizer`  which converts a collection of raw documents to a matrix of TF-IDF features

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
X = pd.DataFrame({'Project Title': ['hello stackoverflow', 'text column', 'scikit learn', 'machine learning projects']})
vect = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
tfidf = vect.fit_transform(X['Project Title'])
X_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(matrix.todense(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
```